# XcodeでみるCPU使用率とは

Tags: xcode

XcodeのデバッグナビゲーターでCPU使用率をみているのですが、100%を超えた値が表示されています。
アプリは普通に動いているのですが、このCPU使用率とはMAX100というわけではないのでしょうか。
ちなみにiPadAir2に作成したアプリを実行して試してみました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CPUの値が100%とは、1コア当たりを100%ととした値になります。
Air2は3コアだったはずなので本当のMAX値は300%になりますね

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます！確かに「CPU」を選択して表示されたメーター？みたいな画面では300％がMAXになっていました。勉強になりました。